# Proof that $\int_0^b \int_0^x f(t) dt dx = \int_0^b x f(x) dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, proof-verification

I have the following statement to prove/disprove:

> If $f$ is a continuous function in the interval $[0,b]$ using the fundamental theorem of calculus and integration by parts, we have  $$\int_{0}^b\int_{0}^xf(t)\,dt\,dx=\int_{0}^bxf(x)dx$$

So using integration by parts, as hinted, we have
$$\int_{0}^b\int_{0}^xf(t)\,dt\,dx\overset{?}{=}\int_{0}^bxf(x)dx$$
$$x\int_{0}^xf(t)\,dt\bigg|_0^b-\int_{0}^bxf(x)dx \overset{?}{=}\int_{0}^bxf(x)dx$$
$$b\int_{0}^bf(t)\,dt\overset{?}{=}2\int_{0}^bxf(x)dx$$
That is readily false. Am I right? Also, deriving both sides would have been valid?

Comment: What is $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_0^x\ f(t) \mathrm{d}t$?

Comment: @EricTowers $f(x)$, I think(I may be wrong)

Comment: Okay.  That's not a sticking point.  Yay.

Comment: On the RHS of the given, have you tried $u = x, \mathrm{d}v = f(x)\mathrm{d}x$?  You should get something rather similar to something written above...

Comment: @EricTowers Yes! It is similar, but not equal:
$$\int_0^b xf(x)=x\int_0^xf(x)dx \bigg|_0^b -\int_0^b\int_0^xf(t)dtdx$$
$$\implies\int_0^b xf(x)=b\int_0^bf(x)dx -\int_0^b\int_0^xf(t)dtdx$$
$$\implies\int_0^b\int_0^xf(t)dtdx=\int_0^b(b-x)f(x)dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the formula as you have given it is correct: take for example $f(t)=6t$ and work out both sides step by step.

However, there is the following more accurate version: using integration by parts for the LHS, take
$$u=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt\ ,\quad \frac{dv}{dx}=1\ ,\quad
  \frac{du}{dx}=f(x)\ ,\quad v=x\ .$$
This gives
$$\eqalign{LHS
  &=\left[x\int_0^x f(t)\,dt\right]_0^b-\int_0^b xf(x)\,dx\cr
  &=b\int_0^bf(t)\,dt-\int_0^b xf(x)\,dx\cr
  &=\int_0^b (b-x)f(x)\,dx\ .\cr}$$
For the last step note that since we are talking about definite integrals,
$$\int_0^b f(t)\,dt\quad\hbox{and}\quad \int_0^b f(x)\,dx$$
are exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, that seems right. Too bad I was given the "broken" statement. It may have been so that it was possible to disprove it, which was easier. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

This is called as Dirichlet rule for integration. For the proof, set $g(y)=\int_{a}^{y}\int_{a}^{x}f(t)\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}x-\int_{a}^{y}(x-a)f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ and apply the Leibnitz rule to differentiate. Then show that $g^{\prime}(y)=0$, i.e., $g$ is constant. This will lead you to $g(a)=g(b)$, which will give you the desired equality.

Comment: Thank you very much! So the posed question was a false version of the true statement...